# SQL Remove duplicates maintaining earliest/latest dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been unable to find an answer that works for my circumstances, although i'm sure it's reasonably straightforward..

I have data showing Customer claims, each claim contains 'From' and 'To' date columns, with multiple rows per claim (ie, multiple time periods within a single claim), and multiple Customers

I would like to remove duplicate lines for the claims, while maintaining the earliest and latest possible dates

so from

```
Customer        Claim_ID        Code    From_Date   To_Date     Charge
023718421001    300038310129    A360    06/05/2017  13/05/2017  47
023718421002    300039554280    A360    31/07/2017  15/08/2017  47
023718421002    300039554280    A361    02/09/2017  12/09/2017  160
023718421002    300039573833    A100    01/09/2017  02/09/2017  100
```

To

```
Customer        Claim_ID      From_Date   To_Date     
023718421001    300038310129  06/05/2017    13/05/2017  
023718421002    300039554280  31/07/2017    12/09/2017
023718421002    300039573833  01/09/2017    02/09/2017
```

Apologies if this has been answered many times and my searches have been way off, any help greatly appreciated.

many thanks,

Alan

Comment: Please see the following blog post describing this exact situation in detail https://thesqlserverdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/03/deleting-duplicate-records-from-table.html?view=magazine

Comment: You have to show us what have you tried so far and what results it shows instead of the expected ones

Comment: @alanW, did the blog post above or answers below help?

Comment: @DanielMarcus  thanks for the link, it was very informative. golden ratio's answer below gave me the exact result I was after. Apologies for not posting my attempted code beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a group by Claim_ID, minimum on the From column, maximum on the To Column:

```
Select 
    max(customer) Customer,
    [Claim_ID],
    min([From_Date]) [From_Date],
    max([To_Date]) [To_Date]
from
    table
group by
    [Claim_Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result by GROUP BY Customer, Claim_ID

```
SELECT      Customer
            ,[Claim_ID]
            ,MIN([From_Date]) [From_Date]
            ,MAX([To_Date]) [To_Date]
FROM        TableName
GROUP BY    Customer, [Claim_Id]
```